# How do I configure a joystick or gamepad?

Tags: logitech, gamepad, joystick

I recently received a Logitech Rumblepad 2 (a joystick, like a PS2 controller) from a friend.

How would I configure this in Ubuntu? If possible, I would prefer to use a GUI utility.

I tried `jstest-gui`, but it shows my accelerometer!

Comment: Do you mind to say what brand name and model your joystick is?

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo: never!!!! :D (joking) *updating the question*

Comment: jscalibrator:
- no longer available,
- bugged
- won't be fixed Ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...sw/+bug/416628 Looking for an alternative

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is possible to calibrate Joysticks in Kubuntu using KDE's system settings. This is a bit of an "overkill" solution, as of course it requires KDE (and most Ubuntu users will not want this).

[image]

I did not have my joystick plugged in for the above screenshot, but I have tried it before and it works.

## JStest gtk and joystick

These are two tools included in the Ubuntu repositories that I have not tested recently (I found these when looking for other options). The first of the two, jstest-gtk, is a graphical tool, and `joystick` is a set of commandline utilities.

You can install them using:

```
sudo apt-get install jstest-gtk
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install joystick
```

Jstest-gtk is a front end to joystick's commandline tools.

Comment: I installed `kde-system-settings` but can't find these settings.  Where exactly are they?  Do I need to install another package?

Comment: @Seth type joystick in the search box and input devices should be highlighted.

Comment: I must need another package then.. See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h2437.png

Comment: @Seth I would need to track it down :(

Comment: I have all the major DEs on my system so I guess I must have missed something.

Comment: I've tried `jstest-gtk` but it doesn't seem to allow me to *change* anything.. useful for testing though.

Comment: jstest-gtk worked great for me, I paired my ouya controller and everything was registered. Very cool!

Answer (score 37):

## This process will work for Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) and older versions. For the newest versions please refer to this [Answer by RolandiXor](https://askubuntu.com/a/270111/9598). Thank you.

Not tested by me, but found in a link provided at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=393425, I hope this may help.

> ### Install joystick and jscalbrator
>
> `sudo apt install joystick jscalibrator`
>
> ### then run the calibration processes
>
> `jscal -c /dev/input/js0` (this is
>   my joystick location, check yours)
>
> `jstest /dev/input/js0` (or wherever) If
>   I remember correctly, this should
>   return 0 for no error.
>
> ### run jscalibrator
>
> `jscalibrator`
>
> and it should
>   recognize the type of gamepad
>   correctly and recognize all of your
>   buttons, and axis

[image]

[image]

There is also an application called [jstest-gtk](https://github.com/Grumbel/jstest-gtk), which seems to do something like that, I post here a screenshot and the link for you: https://github.com/Grumbel/jstest-gtk (This software may need to be compiled in order to make it work)

[image]

Comment: Time to update this answer: $ sudo apt-get install jscalibrator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jscalibrator

Comment: The answer was updated. Please refer to this answer by RolandiXor for further support on newer versions. Thank you http://askubuntu.com/a/270111/9598

Comment: I assume the first screenshot shows jscalibrator? That's exactly the software I'm searching for. Since it doesn't exist in newer versions of Ubuntu anymore, is there an alternative that actually shows what any particular button press should look like? Because I don't know what buttons 0-11 are supposed to map to so I don't know how to use jstest or jscal. If there is no such software, is there some picture that shows a reference mapping? I'm guessing X=0, O=1, square=2, triangle=4 but that's about as far as I can guess.

Comment: does some of theese tools give me the ability to choose what input driver the controller should use? like udev for example?

Answer (score 25):

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and have Logitech Rumblepad 2. And what I did was installing these,  [joystick](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/joystick/) and [jstest-gtk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jstest-gtk/). It's already been calibrate to default and joystick device is detected right. Just plug and play.

If you need to calibrate and save your configuration you can do this,
open jtest-gtk, You will see this,

[image]

You can calibrate by double click on the device.

[image]

Hope it will help you out as it has done to me.

Comment: How do you save your configuration? Where is it saved? In which file?

Comment: Nice. Finds the tilt and all buttons of my old Microsoft Sidewinder Controller.

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to @B. du Garay  for pointing out in comments that `anti-micro` is [now available in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=antimicro) (20.04 only), install it with:

```
sudo apt install antimicro
```

---

The answers here are getting a bit old now, and users seem to be having issues again, so this is a 2016 solution to configuring your joystick or gamepad on Ubuntu.

You can use `antimicro`, it is a fork of `joy2key` and has a `GUI`, use this `PPA` for 12.04 to 15.10

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ryochan7/antimicro
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install antimicro
```

For 16.04+ use this `PPA`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install antimicro
```

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/gamepad-keyboardmouse-mapping-app.html)

[image: Screnshot of AntiMicro and key mapping]

Comment: This also worked with the `droidpad` application which allows  android phone to be used as gamepad.

Comment: This application doesn' tedetct my USB gamepads on 15.10 - they work well on 14.04 though. Any workarounds for 15.10?

Comment: I don't know a work around, it worked for me on 15.10 but here are some things to try, update your kernel and system with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` try installing the xbox driver `sudo apt-get install xboxdrv` reboot after each one. I also updated the answer to include a version for 16.04 if you want to upgrade. @TenLeftFingers

Comment: Thanks Mark Kirby. Turns out my laptop doesn't provide enough power via USB unless the power chord is connected.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers (and to anyone else whose controller is not recognised when plugged in via USB cable) - something **worth trying is a shorter cable**. I had just grabbed the nearest one, which was pretty long. Nothing was recognised. I tried a pretty short one and both a PS2 controller and an Xbox One controller were then found using `ftest /dev/input/by-id/..`

Comment: No 18.04 release. https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro/issues/230 building from source works for me

Comment: Now, from 20.04 Focal, `antimicro` is in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @B.duGaray Thanks, I updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Nice that it's now in Ubuntu 20.10. It doesn't catch the tilt or C and Z buttons of my old Microsoft Sidewinder though.

Comment: Antimicro seems to work perfectly but I need to keep the configuration screen open. Is there a way to background this?

Answer (score 7):

I am currently using qjoypad for mapping keys (even the mouse) to a Logitech Gamepad F310. It's working well for games that are designed with only keyboard and mouse controls in mind. It seems to require being run from cli as `qjoypad --notray`. It does use a GUI.

**How to Install Qjoypad**
First add the GetDeb Games ppa

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb games" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
```

Then update and install package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qjoypad
```

Alternatively download the package [here](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/#download) and install with your favorite package manager.

Comment: qjoypad isn't in ubuntu's repository. Mind giving instructions on how to add it?

Comment: I seem to recall installing via the synaptic package manager. I'll check when I get home, but you can get it at [qjoypad.sourceforge.net](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/).

Decompress the tar.gz and the installation should be as simple as

    `./config`
    `make`
    `make install`

Comment: doesn't look as though the package as been updated in over 3 years. Also doesn't seem like there is a ppa for it, not like it would matter given how there are no updates. It is definitely not in raring's repository. Nvm, found it http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_games?dist=raring

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to get that notray option to run from the launcher

Comment: @Nil at the time of writing this, qjoypad in fact in the Ubuntu repositories.