# Logitech Rumble Gamepad F510

Tags: hardware, games, gamepad

I recently I bought a Logitech F510 gamepad. Unfortunately, it does not work properly for me.
I have tried to calibrate the device with jstest-gtk without any success - I can not get all the axes working properly. So because of this, playing games like Trine or Steel Storm with the gamepad is not possible.

Connecting the gamepad I get following output:

```
[28445.660054] usb 4-3: new full speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
[28446.504708] Registered led device: xpad0
[28446.504858] input: Generic X-Box pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.1/usb4/4-3/4-3:1.0/input/input7
[28446.505403] usbcore: registered new interface driver xpad
```

Following values I get with evtest (all gamepad sticks are in the center):

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0xc21e version 0x2019
Input device name: "Generic X-Box pad"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (Sync)
  Event type 1 (Key)
    Event code 304 (BtnA)
    Event code 305 (BtnB)
    Event code 307 (BtnX)
    Event code 308 (BtnY)
    Event code 310 (BtnTL)
    Event code 311 (BtnTR)
    Event code 314 (BtnSelect)
    Event code 315 (BtnStart)
    Event code 316 (BtnMode)
    Event code 317 (BtnThumbL)
    Event code 318 (BtnThumbR)
  Event type 3 (Absolute)
    Event code 0 (X)
      Value    128
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 1 (Y)
      Value   -129
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 2 (Z)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 3 (Rx)
      Value    128
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 4 (Ry)
      Value   -129
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 5 (Rz)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
    Event code 16 (Hat0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (Hat0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
  Event type 21 (ForceFeedback)
    Event code 80 (Rumble)
    Event code 81 (Periodic)
    Event code 88 (Square)
    Event code 89 (Triangle)
    Event code 90 (Sine)
    Event code 96 (Gain)
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can get the gamepad working properly or if there is a new version of the driver for it?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? Do all the axes show up and do they report reasonable values in jstest? Also calibration is not needed with modern gamepads and will almost always do more harm then good, unless you know what you are doing (unplugging will reset it, so no permanent harm).

Comment: Unfortunately the calibration is needed with my gamepad although it is a modern one. Maybe using the xpad driver for my gamepad does not work good. Does somebody know if there is a driver for this gamepad?

Comment: @Grumbel "Does not work properly" means in my case: one axis (the left one) works ok the second one (the right one) only works in the y direction. Furthermore there seems to be an calibration error on the left axis for the center position. There is no package jscalibrator in the ubuntu repositories for more than a year now.

Comment: To adjust calibration values you can always use `jscal`, but as said, I doubt that this is a calibration issue. Could you provide some more infos on the "not working properly", i.e. use `evtest` and report what values you get on full left, full right and center. Also there exist `xboxdrv` as an alternative to the `xpad` driver, I don't think it supports the f510 out of the box, but it should be possible to hack it together that way. You can contact me via Jabber xmpp:grumbel@jabber.org and I can talk you through.

Comment: @Grumbel Yes I think it is a driver issue. I have contacted Logitech support regarding this problem without any success: "They only support MS Windows".

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a fix to this problem in development or maybe it is even already in a new kernel?

Comment: I have reported this [bug on the Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/902381)

Answer (score 1):

Information provided on this answer: [How do I configure a joystick or gamepad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32031/how-do-i-configure-a-joystick-or-gamepad/32046#32046) may be useful for you, which contains information related to the jstest-gtk and the jscalibrator. Placed here for your convenience:

> Not tested by me, but found in a link provided at:
>   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=393425, I hope this may help.
>
> > ### Install joystick
> >
> > `sudo apt-get update`
> >
> > `sudo apt-get install joystick`
> >
> > ### then install jscalibrator
> >
> > `sudo apt-get install jscalibrator`
> >
> > ### then run the calibration processes
> >
> > `jscal -c /dev/input/js0` (this is
> >     my joystick location check yours)
> >
> > `jstest /dev/input/js0` (or wherever) If
> >     I remember correctly, this should
> >     return 0 for no error.
> >
> > ### run jscalibrator
> >
> > `jscalibrator`
> >
> > and it should
> >     recognize the type of gamepad
> >     correctly and recognize all of your
> >     buttons, and axis
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> There is also an application called [jstest-gtk](https://github.com/Grumbel/jstest-gtk), which seems to do
>   something like that, I post here a screenshot and the link for you:
>   https://github.com/Grumbel/jstest-gtk (This software may need to be
>   compiled in order to make it work)
>
> [image]

I hope this help you.

Good luck!