# logitech f510 and f710 are not working

Tags: usb, logitech, gamepad

Moved to ubuntu 14.04 not so long ago. I had Logitech f510 and f710 while using windows, but I was not able to make them work on my ubuntu system. 
What was done - installed xboxdrv. After it installed qjoypad and jstest-gtk but they are not able to see my gamepads. Tried [Logitech Rumble Gamepad F510](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63138/logitech-rumble-gamepad-f510) and [How do I configure a joystick or gamepad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32031/how-do-i-configure-a-joystick-or-gamepad/270111#270111) with no luck. And find out that actually my problem is that device is not listed in /dev/input and I'm not sure what to do to move it there.

Here is dmesg output:

```
[ 2014.619530] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 2014.639445] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c21e
[ 2014.639450] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2014.639454] usb 3-2: Product: Rumble Gamepad F510
[ 2014.639456] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 2014.639459] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: B289B4F3
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:c21e Logitech, Inc. F510 Gamepad [XInput Mode]
```

With the evtest I can't see device listed and there are no js* files in /dev/input.

Will be glad for any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed it reinstalling ubuntu. No idea what happened.