# Not finding jscalibrator when attempting to install?

Tags: games, joystick

Install joystick  in Ubuntu 14.10

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install joystick
```

then install jscalibrator

```
sudo apt-get install jscalibrator
```

after last sudo, it doesn't find jscalibrator.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That software is unsupported as of Karmic (=2009). Due to the maintainer not [upgrading](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjsw/+bug/416628) the package to GTK2 at that time.

I see no method in installing this software on Ubuntu 14.04 or newer anymore.

Also see: [How do I configure a joystick or gamepad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32031/how-do-i-configure-a-joystick-or-gamepad/270111#270111) It might be possible using a KDE tool.  Good luck :)

---

If you get an error message like that please 1st check the ubuntu package list for that name and you would have seen it does not exist anymore.