# Is it possible to connect Dualshock 4 solely through usb?

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

For the past hour I've been trying to connect my DS4 controller and I've look up different ways and I found out about ds4drv and all that good stuff, but in all of those instances where people have asked, they're connecting their controllers wirelessly. Is it possible to connect straight through usb?

At the moment when I plug my controller in, the controller LED turns blue and that's it. Even if it was connected I was there was a way of my computer telling me that it is or somewhere where I can manage the controller.

Any ideas?

Comment: I use my DS4 by usb, best way to set it up is to install steam, go to big picture mode and here you can configure the controller, then it should just work. For other things like emulators, it should just work and for none steam games  http://askubuntu.com/questions/32031/how-do-i-configure-a-joystick-or-gamepad?rq=1

Comment: So just.... plug it in?

Comment: Yep, more or less, you need to set steam because the button mappings are wrong but it basically just works