# CobaltFlux USB Gamepad doesn't report input? How do I get my computer to recognize the input?

Tags: usb, games, udev, gamepad

I have an old Cobalt Flux Metal Dance Mat for DDR/StepMania, and I can't seem to get my computer to receive any input from it.

some debugging:

dmesg

```
  940.121515] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  940.121517] usb 2-1.6.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  941.307219] usb 2-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  941.419243] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=22ba, idProduct=0109
[  941.419245] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  941.419246] usb 2-1.6: Product: Generic USB Hub
[  941.419247] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Rui Da
[  941.419653] hub 2-1.6:1.0: USB hub found
[  941.419867] hub 2-1.6:1.0: 3 ports detected
[  941.707217] usb 2-1.6.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  941.821974] usb 2-1.6.1: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0268
[  941.821976] usb 2-1.6.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  941.821977] usb 2-1.6.1: Product: Cobalt Flux Controller
[  941.887274] input: Cobalt Flux Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6.1/2-1.6.1:1.0/0003:054C:0268.0006/input/input16
[  941.887481] sony 0003:054C:0268.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [Cobalt Flux Controller] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6.1/input0
```

/dev/input/by-id
 $ ls -la

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 180 Aug 17 09:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 460 Aug 17 09:44 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 17 09:28 usb-04d9_daskeyboard-event-if01 -> ../event3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 17 09:28 usb-04d9_daskeyboard-event-kbd -> ../event2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 17 09:44 usb-054c_Cobalt_Flux_Controller-event-joystick -> ../event11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   6 Aug 17 09:44 usb-054c_Cobalt_Flux_Controller-joystick -> ../js0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 17 09:28 usb-Logitech_G203_Prodigy_Gaming_Mouse_068836563331-event-mouse -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 17 09:28 usb-Logitech_G203_Prodigy_Gaming_Mouse_068836563331-if01-event-kbd -> ../event5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 17 09:28 usb-Logitech_G203_Prodigy_Gaming_Mouse_068836563331-mouse -> ../mouse0
```

evtest

```
$ evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event11: Cobalt Flux Controller
Select the device event number [0-11]: 

I select 11, it outputs a bunch of Event codes', and then says:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)

So then I push all the buttons and there is no output.
```

any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/270111/692175

Comment: currently, jstest-gtk does not detect any input. everything has either negative values, or 0s.

Comment: Try using `evtest` as root, `sudo evtest`, it seems a permission issue see `root root` for joystick nodes.