# How to enable a vibration in a PC gamepad in Xubuntu 18.10

Tags: xubuntu, games, 18.10, gamepad

I have a unknown gamepad for 3-4$ and I connected it to PC to test vibration but I don't know how.

Comment: I think the question is does it have that feature? Cheap gamepads usually don't.

Comment: my gamepad are working on windows 7 i checked this by playing Metal Gear Solid 2

Comment: Did it vibrate?

Comment: of course i can even send a video

Comment: No need. You can try a game in Xubuntu that uses the feature and hopefully it'll work without further configuration.

Comment: ok i will try on steam game

Comment: vibration is not working... any ideas?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/720318/880592

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure a joystick or gamepad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32031/how-do-i-configure-a-joystick-or-gamepad)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The gamepad might not support vibration. If you can edit your post to include the vendor and product IDs for the device it's much easier for other people to know which model you have and whether it should work. You can get this with `lsusb` (assuming it's connected with USB):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 056: ID 045e:02ea Microsoft Corp.
```

In this case I have a connected gamepad with vendor ID `045e` and product ID `02ea`. Those are the IDs for an Xbox One controller.

A gamepad supports vibration if it supports the `FF_RUMBLE` event, which you can check with the `evtest` tool. Here's the output for my Xbox One controller, which does support vibration.

```
$ evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event16: Microsoft X-Box One S pad
Select the device event number [0-16]: 16
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x45e product 0x2ea version 0x301
Input device name: "Microsoft X-Box One S pad"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 304 (BTN_SOUTH)
    Event code 305 (BTN_EAST)
    Event code 307 (BTN_NORTH)
    Event code 308 (BTN_WEST)
    Event code 310 (BTN_TL)
    Event code 311 (BTN_TR)
    Event code 314 (BTN_SELECT)
    Event code 315 (BTN_START)
    Event code 316 (BTN_MODE)
    Event code 317 (BTN_THUMBL)
    Event code 318 (BTN_THUMBR)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value    738
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Flat     128
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value    705
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Flat     128
    Event code 2 (ABS_Z)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     1023
    Event code 3 (ABS_RX)
      Value    482
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 4 (ABS_RY)
      Value   -339
      Min   -32768
      Max    32767
      Fuzz      16
      Flat     128
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max     1023
    Event code 16 (ABS_HAT0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (ABS_HAT0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
  Event type 21 (EV_FF)
    Event code 80 (FF_RUMBLE)
    Event code 81 (FF_PERIODIC)
    Event code 88 (FF_SQUARE)
    Event code 89 (FF_TRIANGLE)
    Event code 90 (FF_SINE)
    Event code 96 (FF_GAIN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```

`Event code 80 (FF_RUMBLE)` means it should support vibration effects.

To test rumble, use `fftest`. You'll need to provide the path to the evdev node for the gamepad, which is included in the output from `evtest`. For my Xbox controller this was `/dev/input/event16`:

```
$ fftest /dev/input/event16
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/event16 opened
Features:
  * Absolute axes: X, Y, Z, RX, RY, RZ, Hat 0 X, Hat 0 Y, 
    [3F 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 ]
  * Relative axes: 
    [00 00 ]
  * Force feedback effects types: Periodic, Rumble, Gain, 
    Force feedback periodic effects: Square, Triangle, Sine, 
    [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 07 01 00 00 00 ]
  * Number of simultaneous effects: 16

Setting master gain to 75% ... OK
Uploading effect #0 (Periodic sinusoidal) ... OK (id 0)
Uploading effect #1 (Constant) ... Error: Invalid argument
Uploading effect #2 (Spring) ... Error: Invalid argument
Uploading effect #3 (Damper) ... Error: Invalid argument
Uploading effect #4 (Strong rumble, with heavy motor) ... OK (id 1)
Uploading effect #5 (Weak rumble, with light motor) ... OK (id 2)
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
```

Use effects 4 and 5 to test rumble effects:

```
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
4
Now Playing: Strong Rumble
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
5
Now Playing: Weak Rumble
Enter effect number, -1 to exit
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! 
But the numbers that got my controller to vibrate were 0 and 4. 5 didn't do anything.

Comment: Im using Linux Mint 21 and I have `Event code 80 (FF_RUMBLE)` and `Uploading effect #4 (Strong rumble, with heavy motor) ... OK (id 1)` but when I press `4` nothing happens no vibration ... ?

Comment: @SlobodanVidovic which gamepad are you using?

Comment: @nondebug I have PlayStation 3 Controller and I opened it and it has two motors for vibration

Comment: Hmm, I just tried with DualShock3 (model CECHZC2U A1) and effects 0, 4, 5 (periodic, strong rumble, weak rumble) all worked for me. Can you share the model number from the label on the back of the controller?

Comment: @nondebug mine's are CECHZC1E and CECHZC2H A1